# VBA excel retrieving both values of a multi column combo box using name property

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I have a class that stores the the name and value of a series of  userform combo boxes and text boxes. Each component is stored in an individual instance which is then stored in an array. I am storing them so they may be retrieved and checked for completeness before moving to the workbook.

```
Class Module: MaterialField

Option Explicit

Private fieldName As String
Private fieldValue As Variant
Private fieldValue2 As String

Property Get Name() As String  
    Name = fieldName 
End Property

Property Get Value() As Variant
    Value = fieldValue
End Property

Property Get value2() As String
    value2 = fieldValue2
End Property

Property Let Name(str As String)
    fieldName = str
End Property

Property Let Value(val As Variant)
    fieldValue = val
End Property

Property Let value2(str As String)
    fieldValue2 = str
End Property
```

Here is the code that uses this class

```
Private Sub FillTblArray()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim str As String

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 3
        Set mats(i, j) = New MaterialField

        If (j = 1) Then
            str = "CB" & i
            mats(i, j).Name = str

            mats(i, j).Value = Me.Controls(str).Value
            mats(i, j).value2 = Me.Controls(str).Column(1).Value
        Else
            str = "TB" & i & (j - 1)
            mats(i, j).Name = str
            mats(i, j).Value = Me.Controls(str).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

```
mats(i, j).Value = Me.Controls(str).Value
```

stores the first column value correctly

```
mats(i, j).value2 = Me.Controls(str).Column(1).Value
```

this line throws an error

I need to find a way to get at both values of the combo box using only the components name

Comment: Remove "value" from  Me.Controls(str).Column(1).Value It should be  Me.Controls(str).Column(1)

Comment: I tried it that way. Now I get an error that says:Could not get column property. Invalid property array index. I assume this is occurring when the is no selection made and the entry is blank. I am still investigating.

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to check beforehand if any selections has been made. But the control combobox does not have a property value, so you cannot write  Me.Controls(str).Column(1).Value